# Could anybody fix this for loop I've created

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm trying to create a game for my CS assignment and I'm stuck with this for loop that won't end my game even though the lives are already at zero.

```
for(life = 3, ai_life = 3; ai_life != 0, life != 0; --ai_life, --life)
```

Comment: Don't write code like this. It's unreadable and therefore you missed what's wrong in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please read up what the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) does

```
for(life = 3, ai_life = 3; ai_life != 0 && life != 0; --ai_life, --life)
```

Comment: All you did was to post a link-only answer with a copy paste of the original code.

Comment: @Lundin If you would have double checked my code against the original code then you will notice a subtle change in the loop condition from a `,` to a `&&`.

Comment: @SergeyL. So subtle it is easy to miss, you should probably make it more explicit what is happening, and how the fix works

Comment: @SergeyL. Specifically, according to your link, `a,b` evaluates `a` and `b` and returns `b`. While not the intended behaviour, why does the loop not end when `life==0`?

Comment: @Baldrickk It will end when `life == 0`, this part would work fine. Since it's generally the purpose of a game to win -- i.e. get the AI's lives to 0 and the OP's code obviously doesn't work, I assumed that this is why. Either way my suggested fix resolves that problem and I would assume since it was accepted that this was the cause.

Comment: @SergeyL. That's what I thought, and of course your answer matches the obviously intended solution.  But being in a `for` loop where both were initialised to the same value and decremented together, it appeared that it would still terminate at the desired time.  Of course 'side effects' in the code that wasn't posted are the reason this didn't happen.  I was just looking at the change from `,` to `&&` and wondering how it changed the behaviour of the code snippet we were given.